# Django - fabric on server

Tags: python, django, fabric

I would like to call "python manage.py installtasks" on my serwer but it doesn't work. On my local computer it works fine:

```
@receiver(config_updated)
def constance_updated(sender, key, old_value, new_value, **kwargs):
    local('python3 manage.py installtasks')
```

On my server (this is a part of my admin.py file by the way):

```
env.hosts = ['my_host']
run('python manage.py installtasks')
```

I tried also:

```
run('/usr/home/my_user/.virtualenvs/app/bin/python /usr/home/my_user/domains/host/public_python/manage.py installtasks')
```

I get only "waiting for [host]" on bottom of my browser and "504 Gateway Time-out" after couple of minutes. Is there any way to see what is going on (any output)?. How should I configure fabric?

Comment: are you using a virtual environment?

Comment: Yes - I am using venv